# Two monitors - primary, secondary?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor, settings, system-settings

I use **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and to motherboard (**GA-Z170-D3H** with **Intel HD Graphic 530**) I have connected **two monitors**. First (primary) on **DVI** and second (secondary) on **VGA** output. Secondary monitor I can turn ON/OFF as needed in settings. 
*Settings means unity-control-center*

**In a situation when is secondary monitor powered OFF:** 
During BIOS and system loading are enabled and used both monitors (naturally), but when is system loading complete and I see login screen, **are both monitors still enabled** and password form is on **secondary monitor (VGA)**, which is a bit impractical. Always I must move cursor away form secondary monitor to primary for transfer login form to primary monitor.

Can I somehow set monitor on DVI output as primary, to **display the login form right there**?

Comment: It isn't very important, but nobody knows?

Comment: I didn't know about the cursor trick thanks! i was typing password blind :)

Comment: @user1159819 You're welcome.. :)